# unix merging character and next line to one line

Tags: unix, sed

$ cat TPSCIS1705291200.err

```
0301705293504895     000003330011868452100001742N
#ERROR - Can not find Account:3504895
04117052912404797-010000005947011868455100001410N
#ERROR - Can not find Account:12404797-010
```

Here I am looking to replace the last character N and next line character # to come in one line

Expected output should be something like

```
0301705293504895     000003330011868452100001742N,#ERROR - Can not find Account:3504895
04117052912404797-010000005947011868455100001410N,#ERROR - Can not find Account:12404797-010
```

please assist I am not able to find the best way for this as character N and # are in different rows

Comment: Please reformat the blocks - it is unclear both what the input is and what you are trying to produce

Answer (score 0):

`sed` won't match newlines. One possible trick is to first "translate" them to other character, then do `sed`-subtitution.

In this code I use [tr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_(Unix)) command to replace newlines to a different 'carriage feed' character (`\f'), then replace it by sed, and finally replace those new lines back

```
cat myfile | tr '\n' '\f' | sed -e "s/N$(echo '\f')/N,#/g" | tr '\f' '\n'
```

Another dirty trick above is doing command-substitution for `echo '\f\` since it cannot be part of the regular expression either!

Working code (in bash for MacOS):

```
-- /tmp » cat in
0301705293504895 000003330011868452100001742N
ERROR - Can not find Account:3504895
04117052912404797-010000005947011868455100001410N
ERROR - Can not find Account:12404797-010
--- /tmp » cat in| tr '\n' '\f' | sed -e "s/N$(echo '\f')/N,#/g" | tr '\f' '\n'
0301705293504895 000003330011868452100001742N,#ERROR - Can not find Account:3504895
04117052912404797-010000005947011868455100001410N,#ERROR - Can not find Account:12404797-010
```

Comment: thanks Herchu i tried it in the unix os doesnt give me desired op

Comment: 16:19:42 [mau-bss-app:/opt/redknee/dist/TEST_export_TPS]$ uname -a
SunOS mau-bss-app 5.10 Generic_150401-13 i86pc i386 i86pc

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are just looking to merge every other line:

```
awk 'NR%2 { printf "%s,", $0; next} 1' input
```

Comment: this is interesting. I've started with changing `ORS` and `-F`. But your stuff seems pretty suitable for such simple input data

Comment: nope, i need the last char N of first line and second line starting with # to be merged together only

Comment: @SonnySanphil, so try at start and you'll see that it has merged as expected

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i ':a;/N$/N;s/\n#/,#/;ta;P;D' file
```

If the current line ends in `N` and the following line begins with a `#` replace the newline with a `,` and repeat. Otherwise print the first line and repeat.